# Cannot select space from form

Tags: php, forms

For some reason I cannot accept values with spaces in them. It accepts all values fine but when there is a space involved it will only take the first word.

On the form page I have this:

```
    <select name=Team[]>
```

On the next page I have this:

```
    $team1=$_POST['Team'];
```

If you need more info I'll share but I'm assuming it's something easy and I'm dumb.

Comment: You're missing your form page code, also do you just echo $team1?

Comment: $_POST['Team']; add single quotes...

Comment: Tried $_POST['Team']; same thing

Comment: on form it should be name="Team"

Comment: can you add the full form page

Comment: The form page is taking content from the DB and displaying it by a drop down. So in the DB team names with spaces will display in the drop down but not on the next page when selected.

Comment: Got it: The issue was actually in the option value.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a multiple select list - 
// change this -

```
<select name="Team[]">
```

the name you have will post as array so the first value will be

```
$_POST['Team'][0];
```

or

```
foreach($_POST['Team'] as $team){
    echo $team;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Team[]" is an array :

```
$team1 = $_POST['Team'][0];
```

In your secure code use [is_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php).

```
if (is_array($_POST['Team']))
    $team1 = $_POST['Team'][0];
else
    $team1 = $_POST['Team'];
```

or :

```
$team1 = (is_array($_POST['Team'])) ? $_POST['Team'][0] : $_POST['Team'];
```